# Vim 8.0: Can't disable autoindent on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, vim

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and install vim by `sudo apt get install vim`. Package version is 8.x. 
Event I `set noautoindent` and `set nosmartindent` but the indentation still happens automatically.
It looks more like a "smart" one because if I type "end" after typing `enter` in a *.rb file, the indentation is automatically removed.

Answer (score 9):

The Ubuntu 18.04 LTS working solution was given by Roman Odaisky in one of the comments. I am just moving it here and expanding on a little bit for the future users, since it took me some time to find a way to disable this annoyance:

1. To turn off all autoindent temporarily in VIM session issue the following command while in vi:

   ```
   :setl noai nocin nosi inde=
   ```
2. To have VIM remember the setting, add it to your `.vimrc`:

   ```
   $ vi ~/.vimrc
   ---
   setlocal noautoindent
   setlocal nocindent
   setlocal nosmartindent
   setlocal indentexpr=
   ```

Comment: Thank you. I had to remove the `---` which resulted in a `E16: Invalid range: ---` on my 18.04LTS, but your answer was invaluable to retain my sanity while editing YAML!

Comment: Has to be in a user's .vimrc, not the systemwide (/etc/vim/vimrc.local) one. Applies to 20.04LTS as well

Answer (score 0):

`:filetype plugin indent off`?

Also consider `'pastetoggle'` to disable indent temporarily for pasting.

Comment: Both "filetype plugin indent off" and "filetype indent off" didn't work. I tried to start vim with --clean option but it's still the same.

Comment: Also `setlocal indentexpr=`? https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/How_to_stop_auto_indenting

Comment: `set indentexpr=` really works. And very helpful document too. Thanks for the help.